# Number of different normalized inner products

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics

Let $u,v\in\{0,1\}^n$ be $0-1$ vectors with $n$ components.

Let $I=\langle u,v \rangle$. Clearly $I$ can take values in $\{0,1,\dots,n-1,n\}$.

How many different values can $$I'=\frac{\langle u,v \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle u,u \rangle\langle v,v \rangle}}$$ take?

The question is essentially, how many different angles can one make?

A calculation is shown here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058925/number-of-different-normalized-inner-products stating the number is around $cn^{2.75}$. Is there a proof for this?

Comment: An interesting question on its own is the cardinality of $A_n=\{a\cdot b|a,b\in \{1,\dots,n\} \}$. If one can show that $|A_n|=O(n^{1.75})$ the above follows from the arguments in the link.

Comment: $$|A_n|=n^2-\sum_{n<p<n^2, prime} \lfloor \frac{n^2}{p}\rfloor.$$
So there seems to be a connection with the distribution of primes.

Comment: Could you explain more as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the explanation of my comment however its not a solution to the problem. For $m\in \mathbb{N}$ let $[m]=\{1,\dots,m\}$. We have
$$A_n=[n^2]-\{m\in [n^2]|\nexists a,b \in [n] \text{ with } m=ab\}\\
\subset [n^2]-\{m\in [n^2]|\exists\; prime\; p>n, \; p|m\}\\
=[n^2]-\{kp\in [n^2]|p>n\; prime, kp<n^2\}\\
$$
When I wrote the comment I made an error and thought there is equal sign everywhere. For a prime $p$ with $n<p<n^2$ we have $kp<n^2$ for all $k\in \{1,\dots,\lceil \frac{n^2}{p}\rceil\}$. Hence
$$|A_n|\leq n^2-\sum_{n<p<n^2, prime} \lceil \frac{n^2}{p}\rceil.$$